# how to push chinese string using apple push notification service in java?

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications

I am able to push normal string to ios devices but dont know how to push chinese string payload to ios devices? I tried converting chinese string to utf-8 charset format but no luck. Please help.

I am using java, notnoop apns library to send push.

Comment: How are you sending your string across the wire? Post some code you've written to help us begin.

Comment: i tried many ways...encoded a string into utf-8 format.one of the ways i tried to to encode is :                                                       Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
Locale.setDefault(Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE);
       
byte[] encoding1 = "你好吗".getBytes("UTF-8");
String string1 = new String(encoding1, "ISO8859-1");

Answer (score 0):

Use UNICODE characters. Java supports it, and it should work if your iOS device has the necessary font. If not, you'll simply see rectangular boxes or something like that.

Comment: i tried UNICODE character as well but no luck...getting push data with \\u character on my iOS device.

Comment: Are you sure if you have the Chinese fonts? Sounds like you don't.